# Laravel Excel - Error Allowed memory size

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I use `Maatwebsite` to load excel files. I'm loading fine several documents, until it gives the next error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /project1/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 582
```

I'm went to `config/excel.php` and update `memoryCacheSize` setting to `128MB`. After do that I run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`. Try load again and returns me the same error.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Your excel files are too big? BTW share the code too, not only the error.

Comment: You will need to increase the `memory_limit` in `php.ini` to say `256M`

Comment: I broke the main file in several small files. And It has worked well before, so I think it's not about the code.
I think I have to clean cache about maatwebsite or phpexcel library but how? @Troyer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your index.php file.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: M It work good for a period of time.
But now doesn't work... returns me this to a file with 10 lines and for a file with 1000 doesn't start loading file...

Comment: -1 meant as much as available memory will be allocated. There must some error will be returned. Post that here we can find it. I have met problem, as the temp directory not writable after some days. So i changed the temp to somewhere. Its worked. Just post the error you have met.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using box/spout for larger files.  I have used both and typically use Maatwebsite for smaller files because of the flexibility of file types.

https://github.com/box/spout

Comment: You can also use https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel which is a Laravel wrapper over Spout.

Answer (score 3):

You have to increase the memory limit of PHP. You have many ways to do this.

First if you want to check the actual memory limit  you need to create a PHP file (we can name it as php.php) or put it in an action inside any controller, and put following code in it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); exit;?>
```

First way to change memory_limit, this way modify the momeoty_limit for all proyects running in PHP:

Firstly you need find your php.ini, this data is in the phpinfo();

[image]

1. Edit php.ini .Search "memory_limit" in your php.ini, and change the value of it. If no "memory_limit" found, add the following line at the end of php.ini
   memory_limit = 128M ; /* Change the 128M to your needs */
   Save file.
2. Reset apache.

   sudo service apache2 restart

Second option is to put it in the index.php inside your laravel proyect as  @Giri Annamalai M tell you above.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

This option will modify the memory limit to all proyect... If you put -1, this means that there is no limit.(dependes in compute memory)

Other option is to indicate the memory limit in the controller, inside the action indicete the memory limit:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Remember that -1 is always NO LIMIT. Maybe this is no the best secure and performance way to indicate the memory limit. You have other ways to edit the memory like the .htaccess... But i think that the 3rd is one of the best in this ocation.

Answer (score 2):

In 2021 with version 3.1 non of this works.

I got it working with [WithChunkReading](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did some debugging to see what scenarios decreased the memory usage of Laravel Excel.

My best results where using a DTO, one that only contained simple variable types.
Casting objects like Carbon or BigDecimal to string also saved some memory usage.

in the Export you can remove the `withMapping` trait because the DTO properties will do that trick for you. If you want you can change the order of the DTO's properties.

And remove the `ShouldAutoSize` trait, [as suggested by the maintainer](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1728#issuecomment-410530107)

e.g.

```php
class Row {
  public int $id;
  public string $created_at;
}
```

```php
class UserExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        $users = User::query()->all();

        return $users->map(
            function ($user) {
                $row = new Row();
                $row->id = $user->id;
                // cast objects like Carbon or BigDecimal to string
                $row->created_at = $entry->created_at->format('d-m-Y');

                return $row;
            }
        );
    }
}
```